# Displaying error messages on the console when running an executable file inside a Perl script

Tags: perl, system

I made a very simple Perl script, which runs another executable file using the "system" command.
The following is a rough skeleton of it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Doing some processing.....
# blah...blah...blah...

# $bin_file is an executable file
system("$bin_file $arguments");
```

I'd like to see the results from my shell console.
All the standard output and standard errors generated from $bin_file are displayed correctly, but the problem is if there are some errors like segment fault with $bin_file, then  it does not show up at all.

Could you please advise me how to make these OS error messages also appear on the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh? A seg fault doesn't cause any output. You can check the error yourself, though:

```
die "Can't launch child: $!\n"                 if $? == -1;
die "Child killed by signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited with error ".($? >> 8)."\n"  if $? >> 8;
```

Comment: (It's possible to map signal numbers to signal names using a combination of Config module's `$Config{sig_num}` and `$Config{sig_name}`.)